# Retrieving array value from object array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to retrieve the array value name under my onRegister function. But I don't think arrayFullNames.name is correct.

```
     var arrayFullNames = [
        {name: 'David', surname: 'Jones', age: 29},
        {name: 'Jack', surname: 'Sparrow', age: 33},
        {name: 'Monkey', surname: 'Idontknow', age: 9},
        {name: 'JavaScript' , surname: 'Something', age: '6 weeks'}
    ];

    function onRegister(){
      var userQuestion = prompt("What is your name", '');

    if(userQuestion == arrayFullNames.name){
      alert('name match');
     }else{
      alert('no match');
     }
  }
```

Comment: The first answer here might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-an-array-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

> The some() method tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function.

```js
var arrayFullNames = [{ name: 'David', surname: 'Jones', age: 29 }, { name: 'Jack', surname: 'Sparrow', age: 33 }, { name: 'Monkey', surname: 'Idontknow', age: 9 }, { name: 'JavaScript', surname: 'Something', age: '6 weeks' } ];

function onRegister() {
  var userQuestion = prompt("What is your name", '');
  if (arrayFullNames.some(({name}) => name === userQuestion)) {
    alert('name match');
  } else {
    alert('no match');
  }
}
onRegister()
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays works based on indexes not like objects. Try the following

```
var arrayFullNames = [
    {name: 'David', surname: 'Jones', age: 29},
    {name: 'Jack', surname: 'Sparrow', age: 33},
    {name: 'Monkey', surname: 'Idontknow', age: 9},
    {name: 'JavaScript' , surname: 'Something', age: '6 weeks'}
];

function onRegister(){
  var userQuestion = prompt("What is your name", '');
  for(var i=0; i< arrayFullNames.length; i++){
    if(userQuestion == arrayFullNames[i].name){
      alert('name match');
      return true;
    }
  }
  alert('no match');
  return false;
}
```

Comment: You are missing your `[i]` in your if-statement at `arrayFullNames.name`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [array.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) function to solve this issue:

```
if (arrayFullNames.indexOf(function(obj) { 
  return userQuestion == obj.name;
}) > -1) {
  alert('name match');
} else {
  alert('no match');
}
```

`indexOf` returns -1 if there was no match in the array, otherwise it returns the index of the match.

You could also use [array.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) in a similar fashion.